# Vue: Auto-format/lint: move <script> before <template> tags

Tags: vue.js, format, vuejs3, eslint, prettier

Is there a way to configure ESLint/Prettier or similar tooling to automatically refactor `.vue` files in a way that `<script>` tag will be moved to the beginning of the file above the `<template>` tag?

From:

```html
<template>
  …
</template>

<script>
  …
</script>
```

To:

```html
<script>
  …
</script>

<template>
  …
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a eslint rule for that: [vue/component-tags-order](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/component-tags-order.html)